# Ordered list number shown at the bottom in IE7

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-7

I have a page with an ordered list and it's rendering fine in all browsers except IE7. In IE7, the listing numbers shown at the bottom of the `<li>`; actually the list contains only a `<textarea>`.

Here is the code looks like, view it in IE7 you can see the numbers shown in the bottom of each `<li>`.

```
<ol style="padding-left:25px;">
<li style="margin-bottom:10px;"><textarea name="" id="" cols="5" style="width:400px; min-height:100px;"></textarea></li>
<li style="margin-bottom:10px;"><textarea name="" id="" cols="5" style="width:400px; min-height:100px;"></textarea></li>
<li style="margin-bottom:10px;"><textarea name="" id="" cols="5" style="width:400px; min-height:100px;"></textarea></li>
<li style="margin-bottom:10px;"><textarea name="" id="" cols="5" style="width:400px; min-height:100px;"></textarea></li>
</ol>
```

See the JS Fiddle..
http://jsfiddle.net/GFRBZ/2/

Comment: @akhilpaul - Please remember to mark up your code snippets as I have in the above edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, actually I can't see the stackoverflow editor in FF but fine in EE. Thats what happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `textarea { vertical-align:text-top; }`